# How to write extension method that work with base class

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Idea is to have extension method that extend my functionality.

So instead of having something like this:

```
 return Add(Add(storage.GetFirst(), 3), 7);
```

I want have something like this:

```
return storage.GetFirst().Add(3).Add(7);
```

Problem with extension methods is that they have to be static in static class.
This is simplify example of what I want to do.

```
 public class Storage
    {
        public int GetFirst()
        {
            return 100;
        }
        public int GetAll(int x, int y)
        {

            // ... 
            return x + y;
        }
    }
    public abstract class MyBase
    {
        protected Storage storage;
        protected MyBase()
        {
            storage = new Storage();
        }

        public int Add(int what, int howMuch)
        {
            return storage.GetAll(what, howMuch);
        }

    }

    public class MyClass : MyBase
    {
        public int method1()
        {
            return Add(Add(storage.GetFirst(), 3), 7);

            //I want have something like this:
            // return storage.GetFirst().Add(3).Add(7);
        }
    }
```

Off course classes Storage, MyBase and MyClass must not be static. Logic is simplify to have clean and simple example so relation between classes must stay same. 
What I want to do is to make Add method to be extension method, but leave everything else "more less same".

Is this possible to do and how?

Comment: Learn fluent code pattern. Your methods must return instance of the according classes.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev - What does "according classes" means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative solution would be to make your Storage class actually store something:

```
public class Storage
{
    private int currentValue;

    public Storage GetFirst()
    {
        this.currentValue = 100;
        return this;
    }

    public Storage Add(int toAdd)
    {
        this.currentValue += toAdd;
        return this;
    }

    public int GetResult()
    {
        return this.currentValue;
    }
}
```

This way your call would be:

```
int result = new Storage().GetFirst().Add(3).Add(5).GetResult();
```

Comment: I came up with something similar. +1 :)

Comment: Storage does storing something, I just waned to simplify code. I like your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Have one static class for extensions and use something like:

```
internal static T Map<T> (this int source, Func<int, int, T> function, int extraParam) {
    function (source, extraParam);
}
```

Then you can make your add method something like:

```
storage.GetFirst ().Map (Add, 3).Map (Add, 7);
```

Comment: What is this " =>function (source, extraParam);" ? Can you be more specific.

Comment: That's C#6 feature for not needed `{ }` if it is only one statement. Edited to old syntax.

Comment: Where does the `Add` comes from? Add is an instance method. How that works without an instance?

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel `Add` is a method. Because `Map` accepts `Func<int, int, T>`, and `Add` is just that type function. That's treating functions as class instances.

Answer (score 2):

Without modifying any of your code, it is possible to achieve what you're trying to do. But your current design makes it hard to do. You should have some storage in `Storage` class. There is no storage in `Storage` class despite of its name.

```
public class StorageValue
{
    public StorageValue(Storage storage)
    {
        this.Storage = storage;
    }

    public StorageValue(Storage storage, int value)
    {
        this.Storage = storage;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public Storage Storage { get; private set; }
    public int Value { get; private set; }

    public StorageValue GetFirst()
    {
        return new StorageValue(Storage, Storage.GetFirst());
    }

    public StorageValue Add(int value)
    {
        return new StorageValue(Storage, Storage.GetAll(Value, value));
    }

    public int GetValue()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}

public static class StorageExtensions
{
    public static StorageValue ToStorageValue(this Storage storage)
    {
        return new StorageValue(storage);
    }
}
```

Which these couple of classes, you can call the methods like this

```
public class MyClass : MyBase
{
    public int method1()
    {
        return storage
            .ToStorageValue()
            .GetFirst()
            .Add(3)
            .Add(7)
            .GetValue(); 
    }
}
```

If you want `Add`, `GetFirst` to be the extension methods, you may do it now with `StorageValue` class. But it makes more sense to be in `StorageValue` class itself.

That said, @ Manuel Zelenka's answer is similar to mine which looks better. You may adapt any of them.